# I can't preview multiple uploaded images. Not a duplicate

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an uploader function that works, but doesn't preview the image being uploaded like it does the unique file name. I used the window.fileReader function like suggested.

I have dragover and drop addEventListeners, but for some reason I can't get the image data to preview in the "prev-img" div. Any help would be apriciated.

```
function multiUploader(config){

    this.config = config;
    this.items = "";
    this.all = []
    var self = this;

    multiUploader.prototype._init = function(){
        if (window.File && 
            window.FileReader && 
            window.FileList && 
            window.Blob) {      
             var inputId = $("#"+this.config.form).find("input[type='file']").eq(0).attr("id");
             document.getElementById(inputId).addEventListener("change", this._read, false);
             document.getElementById(this.config.dragArea).addEventListener("dragover", function(e){ e.stopPropagation(); e.preventDefault(); }, false);
             document.getElementById(this.config.dragArea).addEventListener("drop", this._dropFiles, false);
             document.getElementById(this.config.form).addEventListener("submit", this._submit, false);
        } else
            console.log("Browser supports failed");
    }

    multiUploader.prototype._submit = function(e){
        e.stopPropagation(); e.preventDefault();
        self._startUpload();
    }

    multiUploader.prototype._preview = function(data){
        this.items = data;
        if(this.items.length > 0){
            var html = "";      
            var uId = "";
            for(var i = 0; i<this.items.length; i++){
                uId = this.items[i].name._unique();
                let iMg = this.items[i];  // This is where I thought I'd be able to preview
                var sampleIcon = '<img src="images/image.png" />';
                var errorClass = "";
                if(typeof this.items[i] != undefined){
                    if(self._validate(this.items[i].type) <= 0) {
                        sampleIcon = '<img src="images/unknown.png" />';
                        errorClass =" invalid";
                    } 
                    html += '<div class="dfiles'+errorClass+'" rel="'+uId+'"><div class="prev-img"><img src='+iMg+' /></div><button onclick="closeprev(this);" type="button" class="close">×</button><h5>'+sampleIcon+this.items[i].name+'</h5><div id="'+uId+'" class="progress" style="display:none;"><img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" /></div></div>';
                }
            }
            $("#dragAndDropFiles").append(html);
        }
    }

    multiUploader.prototype._read = function(evt){
        if(evt.target.files){
            self._preview(evt.target.files);
            self.all.push(evt.target.files);

        } else 
            console.log("Failed file reading");
    }

    multiUploader.prototype._validate = function(format){
        var arr = this.config.support.split(",");
        return arr.indexOf(format);
    }

    multiUploader.prototype._dropFiles = function(e){
        e.stopPropagation(); e.preventDefault();
        self._preview(e.dataTransfer.files);
        self.all.push(e.dataTransfer.files);
    }
```

Comment: Use `self`, not `this`, in the event listener functions. Isn't that why you declared that variable?

Comment: That is why it was declared. I'm confused what you're saying.

Comment: Change `let iMg = this.items[i]` to `let iMg = self.items[i]`

Comment: Okay, but putting that iMg variable into the image tag still won't preview the images yet. - Sorry I'm new to these prototyping oop ways.

Comment: This is a lot of code, there might be other problems.

Comment: Gotcha, but I figured it works fine without previewing the actual image, so this may be the issue. I'll let you know when I figure it out.

Comment: Since it's more than that one problem, I've reopened the question. But you need to narrow down the problem.

Comment: I'll see if I can. - Thanks